# Is there any default timeout in java process

Tags: java, process, timeout, runtime, execution

I write a tool in jar to execute an application. This is the code to execute the application

```
String argument1 = workingDirectory +" "+ TC.getName();
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(argument1);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String s = null;

            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                    //theLogger.info(s);


                    if (s.contains("FAILED")){
                        theLogger.info("TC is not passed");
                        TC.setIsNotPassed();
                    }

                    if (s.contains("PASSED")){
                        TC.setIsPassed();
                        theLogger.info("TC is passed");
                    } 

                    if (s.contains("End")) {
                        TC.settIterationNumber();
                        theLogger.info("TC Execution ends");
                        break;  
                    } 
            }
            stdInput.close();
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();
            theLogger.info(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString() + " OK");
        }catch (IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             theLogger.info(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString() + " NOK");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

It's working fine until i got one case where the execution time is more than 30 minutes. It considers the result is failed while the result of application is passed. The code works correctly for the cases with execution time less than 30 minutes. In my code, I don't set up any timeout. Is there any default timeout from Java process?

Comment: What do you mean in `result is failed`? You see some exception? or something else?

Comment: What is the exact exception ? And which line throws it ?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. After execution, the application will return some values such as result which can be passed or failed. With s.contains("PASSED"), the code read the result and be printed in a log file ( i don't attach the code for log file). For cases with execution time less than 30 minutes, the result is well caught either execution is passed or failed. But for the ones which are more than 30 min, it doesn't catch the buffer inputstream so it considers there is no "passed" value. In fact, the execution of application is passed with 32 minutes.

Comment: Also; there is no exception thrown. The code is working fine until the end

Comment: are you sure you want System.out.println(s) ? How much data is being read?

Comment: yes, i need to get the inputstream to indicate the next function. I use it to read the result. I dont understand your question 'how much'. I read all the output data from execution